# MySql Indexing part of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, where-clause

I need to search a medium sized MySql table (about 15 million records).
My query searches for a value ending with another value, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE {column} LIKE '%{value}'
```

- `{value}` is always 7 characters length.
- `{column}` is sometimes 8 characters length (otherwise it is 7).

Is there a way to improve performence on my search?
clearly index is not an option.

I could save `{column}` values in reverse order on another column and index that column, but im looking to avoid this solution.

Comment: Not really, because the wildcard is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> {value} is always 7 characters length

Your data is not mormalized. Fixing this is the way to fix the problem. Anything else is a hack. Having said that I accept it is not always proactical to repair damage done in the past by dummies.

However the most appropriate hack depends on a whole lot of information you've not told us about.

- how frequently you will run the query
- what the format of the composite data is

> but im looking to avoid this solution.

Why? It's a reasonable way to address the problem. The only downside is that you need to maintain the new attribute - given that this data domain appears in different attributes in multiple (another normalization violation) means it would make more sense to implement the index in a seperate, [EAV relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) but you just need to add triggers on the original table to maintain sync using your existing code base. Every solution I can think will likely require a similar fix.

Here's a simplified example (no multiple attributes) to get you started:

```
CREATE TABLE lookup (
   table_name VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
   record_id INT NOT NULL, /* or whatever */ 
   suffix VARCHAR(7),
   PRIMARY KEY (table_name, record_id),
   INDEX (suffix, table_name, record_id)
);

CREATE TRIGGER insert_suffix AFTER INSERT ON yourtable
   FOR EACH ROW
   REPLACE INTO lookup (table_name, record_id, suffix)
   VALUES ('yourtable', NEW.id
   , SUBSTR(NEW.attribute, NEW.id, RIGHT(NEW.attribute, 7
  );  

CREATE TRIGGER insert_suffix AFTER UPDATE ON yourtable
   FOR EACH ROW
   REPLACE INTO lookup (table_name, record_id, suffix)
   VALUES ('yourtable', NEW.id
   , RIGHT(NEW.attribute, 7)
  ); 

  CREATE TRIGGER insert_suffix AFTER DELETE ON yourtable
   FOR EACH ROW
   DELETE FROM lookup WHERE table_name='yourtable' AND record_id=OLD.id
  ;
```

Comment: We have decided to adopt your solution with a little adjusment,
since we have 2 columns in the same table with the same problem,
we added a column to table "lookup" called "column" which indicates which column is searched

Comment: With 5.7, you could use a Virtual column that is the right 7 characters of the real column.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set number of options for the first character, then you can use `in`.  For instance:

```
where column in ('{value}', '0{value}', '1{value}', . . . )
```

This allows MySQL to use an index on the column.

Unfortunately, with a wildcard at the *beginning* of the pattern, it is hard to use an index.  Is it possible to store the first character in another column?